# Difficulty with Long to Wide to Long Format in R

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I am trying to make a graph similar to a correlation plot.  However, my data was in long format and I wanted to only show the lower triangle of the matrix.  Therefore, I took my data and reshaped it using the following:

```
x<-c('A','B','C')
data<-expand.grid(x,x)
data$value<-c(1,2,3,2,1,4,3,4,1)
r.data<-reshape(data, idvar = "Var1", timevar = "Var2", direction = "wide")
colnames(r.data)<-c('Var','A','B','C')
rownames(r.data)<-r.data$Var
r.data$Var<-NULL
```

Next I found the lower triangle portion of my data:

```
get_lower_tri<-function(cormat){
  cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- NA
  return(cormat)
}
r.data_lower<-get_lower_tri(r.data)
```

But when I use `melt()` I now only have one column for variable and values because there is no id.  How would I define an id variable or fix something such that it would be in a standard melted format?

Expected:

```
Var1  Var2   value
 A     A       1
 B     A       2
 B     B       1
 C     A       3
 C     B       4
 C     C       1
```

Comment: Can you show expected

Comment: @akrun Updated to show expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to convert to `matrix` and then `melt` with the `na.rm = TRUE` option

```
library(reshape2)
melt(as.matrix(r.data_lower), na.rm = TRUE)
```